# Why does gdb not break on strcpy?

Tags: c, gdb, breakpoints

Please look at the command line below. I set two breakpoints: one on strcpy and the other on printf. Why did it skip breakpoint 1?

```
root@ninja:~/Desktop/Programs# gcc -g -o exp exp.c
root@ninja:~/Desktop/Programs# gdb -q exp
Reading symbols from /root/Desktop/Programs/exp...done.
(gdb) list
1   #include <stdio.h>
2   #include <string.h>
3   
4   int main()  {
5       char str_a[20];
6       
7       strcpy(str_a, "Hello world!\n");
8       printf(str_a);
9   }
(gdb) break strcpy
Function "strcpy" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y
Breakpoint 1 (strcpy) pending.
(gdb) break printf
Breakpoint 2 at 0x8048300
(gdb) run
Starting program: /root/Desktop/Programs/exp 

Breakpoint 2, 0xb7eabf54 in printf () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
(gdb) i r eip
eip            0xb7eabf54   0xb7eabf54 <printf+4>
(gdb) cont
Continuing.
Hello world!
[Inferior 1 (process 3726) exited with code 015]
```

Comment: It may get optimized and reduced to inline code not a function call actually. Try compiling with no optimization.

Comment: @Rohan I used `gcc -g -O0 -o exp exp.c` but it did not work.

Comment: @W.Zhu Check in the assembly code. You'll find that even with `-O0` there is no call to `strcpy`.

Comment: @kaylum I checked and found there was no call to strcpy. It got reduced to an inline code. Now I understand. Thank you.

Comment: Compilers are clever these days.

Comment: Try adding the `-fno-builtin` compiler option.

Comment: IMHO this is a compiler bug.  If the source has a call to strcpy(), and optimization is off, then the compiler should insert a call to strcpy().  Is debugging not difficult enough as it is?

Comment: @kaylum Would you please add your comment as an answer so it will be apparent on the Unanswered list that this question is no longer live?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The first breakpoint is pending.

```
(gdb) break strcpy
Function "strcpy" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y
Breakpoint 1 (strcpy) pending.                                                 <<here
```

try: `(gdb) break 7`

7 being the line number.